# What is the running time of this reverse string algorithm?

Tags: java

So there is an algorithm that takes in a char array such as "Alice likes Bob" and reverses it so we have "Bob likes Alice". Here is the code for the algorithm:

```
public static void reverseWords(char[] input) {
   int n = input.length;
   //First, reverse the whole string.
   reverse(input, 0, n - 1);

   //Second, Reverses each word in the string.
   int start = 0, end = 0;
   while (start < n) {
       while (start < end || start < n && input[start] == ' ') {
           ++start; // Skip spaces chars.
       }
       while (end < start || end < n && input[end] != ' ') {
           ++end; // Skip non-spaces chars.
       }
       reverse(input, start, end - 1);
   }
}
public static void reverse(char[] array, int start, int end){
    while(start<end){
        char tmp = array[start];
        array[start++] = array[end];
        array[end--] = tmp;
    }
}

public static int find(char[] array, char c, int start) {
   for (int i = start; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (array[i] == c) {
           return i;
       }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Can someone explain this code runs in 0(n) time? Also what is the purpose of function find? I dont see find being called anywhere.

Comment: A function that isn't called has no purpose.

Comment: and its not being called right? So I think its a mistake in the book

Comment: Running time isn't the same thing as computational complexity. Which are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you are learning ... but you need to learn to get the terminology correct.

> What is the running time of this reverse string algorithm?

The running time is the time it takes the algorithm to run.  Obviously, that depends on the hardware you are running it on, the compiler, the inputs you provide ... and so on.  Basically, that is not a meaningful question to ask us.  If you really do need to know the running time .... you *measure* it.

> Can someone explain this code runs in O(n) time?

Now this **is** a meaningful question.  You are no longer asking about running times: measured or estimated.  You are now asking about a *computational complexity* measure for an algorithm.  This is about analysing the code to determine how the running time<sup>1</sup> *varies depending on the size of the problem*; i.e. the inputs.

Yes it is `O(N)`.

To figure out why (informally) break down the parts of the code into smaller chunks, and figure out what each chunk is doing, and how many times it is going to "touch" (read or write) each character in the input.  Then accumulate them to give an algebraic "formula".

Does that formula `f(n)` look like `C1 * n + C2`?  Or can you prove that `f(n)` is less than some `C1 * n` as `n` gets very large?

(I'm pretty sure that I can ... but I will leave the details to you!)

> Also what is the purpose of function `find`.  I don't see `find` being called anywhere.

It looks like a mistake in the book.

The *ostensible* purpose of the `find` method is to find a position in an array where a given character occurs.  But as you say, it isn't used.

Blame it on poor quality control in writing / editing / publishing.  It happens.

---

<sup>1 - Well ... not actually real running time.  What we normally do is to count something that is a theoretical proxy for running time; e.g. primitive operations like read and writing variables.  This does not and cannot give you a measure of *real* time.  But since primary purpose of complexity analysis is for chosing between algorithms, that typically doesn't matter.  And when it does, then you need to resort to measuring and comparing running times.</sup>